# Hacer transición con hover para modificar el radius border de un div con un valor determinado

Tags: html, css, css3, hover

Espero tengan un excelente día. Estoy empezando con programación web intentando hacer una pagina web con una imagen conteniendo un div con un texto, este div llevaría un hover que al activarse modificaría el border radius y lo cambiaria a 120px, pero no logro hacer la transición. La mayoría de información que he consultado hasta ahora no ha sido de gran ayuda. Agradecería mucho una ayuda

Esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="fondo">
        <div class="inicio">
    <article id="texto">    
    <h1>Bienvenidos al sitio</h1>
    <p>p&aacute;ginas web con hover</p>
    </article>
</div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">

.inicio {

    width: 300px;
    height: 450px;
}

.inicio:hover {

    border-radius: 120px;
}


#texto {

    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    
}

#fondo {
    
    background-image: url(../Imagen/page.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 700px;
    height: 600px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes bien aplicado el hover sober el contenedor al que quieres darle la animación, pero te faltaría aplicarle la propiedad de CSS **transition**, facilitándole el tiempo que quieres que suceda así como el modo. En este ejemplo que te facilito abajo sobre tu propio código, lo que he hecho es pedirle que se realice la acción en 0,8 segundos y que lo haga de manera uniforme aplicando un **all** sobre todo el contenedor.

He modificado ligeramente tu css para que visualmente se entienda sin problemas el cambio que se ha hecho en la animación:

```css
.inicio {

    width: 450px;
    height: 450px;
}

.inicio:hover {
    background-color:red;
    /*border-radius: 120px;*/
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transition: .8s all;
}


#texto {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: 38%;
    padding: 15px;
}

#fondo {
    
    background-image: url(../Imagen/page.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 700px;
    height: 600px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="fondo">
        <div class="inicio">
    <article id="texto">    
    <h1>Bienvenidos al sitio</h1>
    <p>p&aacute;ginas web con hover</p>
    </article>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

A continución comparto un enlace con [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) sobre el uso y comportamiento de esta propiedad de CSS, **[transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)**, por si te fuera de ayuda y/o utilidad.

Comment: La propiedad `transition` debería estar solo en `.inicio`, si la dejas en `.inicio:hover`, el efecto solo se muestra cuando el mouse pasa por encima, pero no al salir.

Comment: Esto que comenta Triby es totalmente cierto. Como en las especificaciones de la pregunta no figura esta necesidad no la he dejado preparada en el código, solo se requería al activar el hover. Pero si fuera necesario hacerlo en el mouseleave puedes hacer como comenta Triby.

Answer (score 1):

Agrega la transición y el cambio con CSS:

```
div {
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

div:hover {
    border-radius: 120px;
}
```

Nota: si tienes un dispositivo móvil, el `hover` es un poco problemático; se queda activo al pasarlo encima. Esta respuesta **acepta** completamente ser editada para arreglar esto.

Espero que tengas un excelente día. :D